# how to search Table cell in iphone application

Tags: objective-c, iphone

i have develop an  RSS iphone application.
as the data come from xml feed in table cell i am fail to implement search functionality in it.
following is the code in which the date is displayed in table cell

```
    int blogEntryIndex1 = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] -1];

  NSString  *imgstring=[[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex1] objectForKey: @"image"];
    NSString *headline=[[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex1] objectForKey: @"title"];
    //code given to me
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imgstring];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
cell.imageView.image=img;
    cell.textLabel.text=headline;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
```

can anybody help me to implement search bar i am trying on this since last 5 days but I have failed in implementing it.
I will be waiting for your replies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315039/how-to-search-a-uitableview)