# How to search a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, search

Right so I know there are about a billion questions on SO about this subject, but they all appear to link to the same old blog posts about implementing a UISearchBar, or Apple docs. What I want to know is, is there a proper tutorial out there for implementing the UISearchDisplayController class to search through either an array/dictionary and update a UITableView based on that?

I've followed about 10 different variations of tutorial on this topic and none of them yield the expected result. Some tutorials simply show you one line of code and expect you to figure it out, so all I'm asking if is there a tutorial out there which goes through step by step how to to implement search functionality within an iOS app?

Heck if I figure this out eventually I might write a tutorial myself!

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the blogs post and try to understand how they have used,May be,you would require to modify to fit under requirement,Assume the articles are more than sufficient to understand and using `UISearchDisplayController` .

[iPhone/iPad UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController Asynchronous Example](http://blog.patrickcrosby.com/2010/04/27/iphone-ipad-uisearchbar-uisearchdisplaycontroller-asynchronous-example.html)

[Cancellable asynchronous searching with UISearchDisplayController](http://deeperdesign.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/cancellable-asynchronous-searching-with-uisearchdisplaycontroller/)

[A simple tutorial of UISearchDisplayerController](http://www.cocoabob.net/?p=67)

Comment: Hey thanks for this answer, I eventually ended up figuring it out using a combination of the articles above with Apple's sample code.

Comment: I should point out I did eventually write a tutorial on this: http://tomsbigbox.com/search-a-uitableview/